# what is need of integer and SNORM textures

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

What is the advantage or need of integer and SNORM textures? when do we use (-1,0) range for textures?
Any example where we need specifically integer or SNORM textures?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_snorm.txt,
signed normalized integer texture formats are used to represent a floating-point values in the range `[-1.0, 1.0]` with an exact value of floating point zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is nice for storing noise, especially Perlin.
Better than float textures because no bits wasted on the exponent.

Unfortunately, as of GL4.4 none of the snorm formats can be rendered to.
You can use the unorm formats and *2-1 for the same effect, although there may be issues with getting an exact 0.